# Query Losing Vital Information During Pagination in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, pagination

I just created a pagination for my webpage which fetches data from my mysql database. My query has a `WHERE` clause where it accepts a php variable and when that is used as a keyword. Here's an extract:

```
SELECT name, category_id, subcategory, image, price, stock FROM home_products WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'
    UNION
    SELECT name, category_id, subcategory, image, price, stock FROM kitchen_products WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'
```

The links to the pages (e.g. Page 1, Page 2 etc) show on the page but whenever I click on them the page shows me an error that the `$search` variable (the keyword in the where clause) cannot be found. I have tried adding the "search" variable at the end of the links in the pagination but it doesn't really do anything that helps (The list of number of pages in the pagination result increases which just causes me more problems). Here's an extract of the code that outputs the pagination:

```
echo "<a href='pagination.php?page=1'>".'|<'."</a> "; // Goto 1st page

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
    echo "<a href='results.php?search='".$_GET['search']."'&page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
};

echo "<a href='results.php?page=$total_pages'>".'>|'."</a> "; // Goto last page `
```

Am I doing something wrong? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Things you can check here:

- your first page link goes to pagination.php, although others go to results.php. Looks like that should not be this way
- your first and last pages don't have the search variable appended to them like the pages in the loop do
- if any of your pages generated from the loop say that "search" cannot be found, then maybe you're mixing submission methods (eg. you are expecting a $_POST['search'], but pass the 'search' parameter in the $_GET)